# when install software, how to find out what is in the addon ?

Tags: plugins

When installing application, there are addon available but are there easy ways to find out what are they like (Libsvg-perl in the application "Inkscape")
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name, which can be found between the brackets, will tell you more about the add-on. Search for this package name in the Software Center. Below the package details are a list of add-ons. The one you mention (Libsvg-perl) is visible in the screenshot below:

[image: Software center showing add-ons]

For any add-ons you want info on, just re-do your search for that package name.

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I searched then, only some of them can be found and addon like "Libsvg-perl" can not found, so what are they ??

Comment: Make sure you set "All software" in the menu "View".

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I still can only found some of them ..but anyway, I think I will just neglect the others

Comment: That seems strange to me, as I can find the package you mentioned without problems. As an alternative, use `apt-cache show libsvg-perl`.

Comment: thanks, I can see the description when type "apt-cache show libsvg-perl", but not in the software center